# Problem building Hybrid Angular App to production. AOT compiler break downgraded components

Tags: angular, angularjs, ng-upgrade

I will try to explain my problem in the best way. I am migrating an AngularJS application to Angular 12. I need the two applications to run in parallel for the migration to be gradual. I used the NgUpgrade library and I'm running the two applications as if they were one.

Some strategies to do this migration suggested a preparation in the JS files, but due to the size of the system, this becomes impossible.

For development everything is running perfectly. The user-visible interface is AngularJS. Screens that are already converted are created in Angular and the component is downgraded. After that, a new route is registered in AngularJS states.js where this component that was downgraded is called.

The problem is when I try to build for production. The AOT compiler seems to "remove" my component drowngrades and in the end I'm stuck with this message:

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBXCa.png)

How am I downgrading the component

```
declare var angular: any;
angular.module('aprove')
.directive(
    'equipamentosCadastro',
    downgradeComponent({ component: EquipamentosCadastroComponent })
);
```

I tried to remove AOT compilation mode but the application won't start and I ended up getting stuck in a dead end. Where with AOT the new components don't open and with JIT compilation the whole system doesn't open :/

I'm not really sure what else I can write here but if you need any more information I'm happy to make it available.

Comment: What file are you in when you call "downgradeComponent"? Are you in the Angular12 files when you call that? Or are you in the AngularJS files when you make that call?

Comment: I'm in Angular 12 files. As I understand, I should put this inside AngularJS files but I don't know how to call this file

Comment: Just for future reference, I have abandoned this conversion strategy using downgradeComponents and adopted this beautiful approach by Torgeir Helgevold [link](https://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/ngupgrade-with-the-angular-router-and-ui-router)